# Why the android kernel logs shows different timestamps(date and time) while booting?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, logcat

I am new to android, I want to know why my kernel logs are showing different date and time.

Whenever I boot my device, I see that the timestamp of kernel logs are not correct: it's not showing the actual date and time while booting.

It shows different a date and time.

The command used to check kernel logs is `logcat -b kernel`

The Android and kernel versions are Oreo and 4.9.

**Example:**

```
Expected Output: date: 12-02 time:15:41:11
Actual Output:  date: 11-11 time: 16:41:12
```

Comment: probably your computer has different timezone settings than your phone. Your phone default logcat timezone is UTC - I thing

Comment: Thanks for response! how to check the device is in UTC or in other timezone

Comment: The Output of "hwclock --debug" command of my PC is shown below        root@D-113174227:~# hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.31.1
System Time: 1575631823.730951
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Using the rtc interface to the clock.
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2019/12/06 11:30:32
Hw clock time : 2019/12/06 11:30:32 = 1575631832 seconds since 1969
Time since last adjustment is 1575631832 seconds
Calculated Hardware Clock drift is 0.000000 seconds
2019-12-06 17:00:31.966686+0530

Comment: Can anyone help me to get correct timestamp for bootlogs while booting?